# what classloader loads the lib directory of an ear in websphere (or in general)?

Tags: java, websphere, classloader

The documentation on classloaders [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp) `( you have to go through the menus... WebSphere Application Server (Distributed operating systems), Version 8.5 > Developing applications > Developing applications in the full profile environment > Class loading )` say this in regards to class loading order:

> 1. The bootstrap, extensions, and CLASSPATH class loaders created by the Java virtual machine
> 2. A WebSphere extensions class loader
> 3. One or more application module class loaders that load elements of enterprise applications running in the server (jars, ejb mods, etc...)
> 4. Zero or more web module class loaders (wars...)

under point 3 it briefly says that `The product enables you to associate shared libraries with an application.` however I'm assuming that refers to the websphere shared libraries feature external to the ear itself.

I cannot find where it says what classloader loads the lib folder of an EAR. Which one is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EAR lib libraries should be loaded by the **application class loader** which is the same with the class loader referred in No 3 point you mention (the **application module class loader**).

[image]

This is more clearly showed in the following shape. The EAR lib libraries belong in the Application Classpath.

[image]

Comment: So this means that all ejb modules in a single ear share the same application class loader? Ah, This makes so much more sense now. my spidey senses are tingling