# Glassfish: Which classloader loads classes from lib directory in ear

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, classloader

I have an EAR with an EJB module running on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 that calls `SerializationUtils.clone` from `apache commons-lang` on a class that is included in the EJB module. commons-lang is packaged in the `/lib`-directory (`<library-directory>`) of the EAR-file. I get the following exception:

> org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: (Class to be cloned)

The same happens if I mimic `SerializationUtils.clone` with my own helper class and put the class in a jar under `/lib`. If I put my helper class in th EJB module, everything is fine.
Having read [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Application Development Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beadf.html) says that

> The Applib class loader loads the library classes, specified during
>   deployment, for a specific enabled module or Java EE application

Does this also include the EARs `/lib`-directory? If yes, it would explain the CNF described above, or is there another reason. The answer to question [what classloader loads the lib directory of an ear in websphere (or in general)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343291/what-classloader-loads-the-lib-directory-of-an-ear-in-websphere-or-in-general) seems to imply that on webspehere EJB module and jars under /lib are loaded by the same classloader.